# Como puedo usar una api externa en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api

Tengo una api rest que realiza la validación  de un numero y que devuelve verdadero o falso, quisiera saber como consumir la api a través de wordpress para que una vez ingresado el numero, muestre un mensaje si es falso o redireccione si es verdadero

Comment: Para conectar a una API **desde tu Wordpress**, que no es lo mismo que programar una API **en tu Wordpress**, lo más simple es usar shortcode o bien mediante hook. Son dos herramientas que te permitirían conectar con el entorno PHP y lanzar desde allí cualquier cosa. Por ejemplo, en los posts donde quieras que hagan llamadas a la API pondrías este shortcode: `[callapi]` y en `functions.php` registras ese shortcode y lo enlazas con una función que te incluye en esa página un botón por decir algo, desde el cual llamarías a la API. Y, si necesitas pasarle datos, programas código Javascript.

Comment: A. Cedano me parece muy interesante lo que me estas diciendo, de casualidad no tendrás un  link en el cual podria informarme sobre esto

Comment: [Aquí tienes una guía bastante completa sobre shortcode](https://raiolanetworks.es/blog/shortcodes/). Puede que al principio parezca arduo, pero es muy sencillo son sólo dos cosas: 1. Poner el shortcode allí donde quieras que ese bloque de código sea llamado; 2. Programar en `functions.php` todo lo necesario para que se ejecute, sea código en el servidor (PHP) o en el cliente (Javascript). Es una herramienta utilísima para personalizar tu sitio sin necesidad de usar un plugin para cada cosa que quieres hacer. Gracias a ellos, en mi sitio, me quité de encima unos 15 plugin.